# How to design db table for credit/debit token with multiple scenario?

Tags: database, database-design, logic

I have scenario to design a table for `tokens` in my system which is based on `employee (Job Seeker & Freelancer)/employer (Company, Freelance Client, Recruitment Agency)`.

I need to create table for `tokens` it can be `credit/debit` but there are multiple scenario I have when `tokens` are getting credited/debited which are as below. This is for only `employee (Job Seeker & Freelancer)` not for `employer`.

**Scenario for credit tokens**

> 1. At signup employee will get 70 tokens as free.
> 2. Employee can buy token ($1/token)
> 3. Employee can upgrade to executive plan and get 80 token
> 4. If employee offer accepted by emplyer than deducted 3 tokens during application for the job will be credited back.

**Scenario for debit tokens**

> 1. Whenever employee sent offer for any job than 3 token will be deducted.
> 2. Employee can bump up his offer so employee can see his offer top in list. (2 for a day OR 7 for a week)
> 3. Employee can create job alert. (1 / alert)
> 4. Employee can boost profile one employee has only one profile. It will deduct 5 token.
> 5. Signup free tokens are only valid for 30 days after 30 days remaining tokens from this 70 will be debited.

I am willing to create table structure as below.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
id (Primary key)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
token (Number of Token)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
transaction_type (Credited/Debited)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
transaction_for 
(signup, buy, upgrade_plan, offer_accepted, 
 applied_job, bump_offer, job_alert, profile_boost, validity expire)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
user_id (Foreign key for user)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
job_id (for the case offer_accepted, applied_job, bump_offer)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
bump_offer_id (for bump_offer)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
job_alert_id (for Job_alert)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

for the case `signup, buy, upgrade_plan, validity expire` there is alredy `user_id` available.

Is it correct structure ? can you please give me some suggestion ?

Comment: As an aside - also consider the scenario - user signs up, spends 30 tokens, buys 30 tokens all in the fist week - should 70 tokens still be deducted 30 days after sign up, or only 40?

Comment: @rowland Yes that is also a point but if user buys new token then first seventy will be considered to be deducted first.